# how can I select 1 item by index the list in a generator result?

Tags: ansible

```
- hosts: local
  vars:
    main_var:
      - {a: 1, b: "foo"}
      - {a: 2, b: "bar"}
```

Then I try to select item and get attribute:

```
search_list: "{{ {{ main_var3 | selectattr('a', 'equalto', 1)}}"
```

But then the search_list is a generator not the dict I want. Then I tried this

```
search_list: "{{ main_var3 | selectattr('a', 'equalto', 1) | list }}"
```

It turns into a list. For this simple example I can do `| first` to get the actual item. However, in more complex result I want to be able to select the item by index similar to following:

```
search_list: "{{ main_var3 | selectattr('a', 'equalto', 1) | list }}[index]"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your index outside of the Jinja delimiters won't indeed work.

> There are a few kinds of delimiters. The default Jinja delimiters are configured as follows:
>
> - `{% ... %}` for [Statements](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures)
> - `{{ ... }}` for [Expressions](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#expressions) to print to the template output
> - `{# ... #}` for [Comments](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#comments) not included in the template output

<sup>*Source: https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#synopsis*</sup>

What you want to do is to add brackets around the variable and filter applied to it:

```yaml
search_list: "{{ (main_var | selectattr('a', 'equalto', 1) | list)[index] }}"
```

---

A complete working task would be:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ (main_var | selectattr('a', 'equalto', 1) | list)[index] }}"
  vars:
    main_var:
      - a: 1 
        b: "foo"
      - a: 1
        b: "bar"
    index: 1
```

Which would yield:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
    a: 1
    b: bar
```

Comment: Thanks it works. I cannot find this () solution in document though.

Comment: Jinja2 reference is specified on [ansible filters documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.3/playbooks_filters.html).