# Ansible Jinja2: How to get nth value of nested dict?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My Playbook looks like this

```yaml
- set_fact:
    vcenter_cluster: "{{ cluster_info.clusters.values[cluster_input.user_input] }}"   

- debug:
    var:  vcenter_cluster
```

The data in `cluster_info.clusters` looks like this

```json
ok: [localhost] => {
    "cluster_info.clusters": {

        "DMZ": {
            "datacenter": "dc",

        },
        "K8S": {
            "datacenter": "dc",

        },
        "Win": {
            "datacenter": "dc",
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to set `vcenter_cluster` to `K8S` when `cluster_input.user_input` is `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    cluster_info:
      clusters:
        DMZ:
          datacenter: dc
        K8S:
          datacenter: dc
        WIN:
          datacenter: dc

    user_input: 1

  tasks:

  - name: Show
    debug:
      msg: "{{ (cluster_info.clusters | list)[user_input] }}"
```

will result in the requested output of

```yaml
TASK [Show] ******
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: K8S
```

Please notice that under certain circumstances there might be a difference in where a list index can start counting with, `0` versus `1`.   As well that Ansible / Python probably will not maintain the order of the dictionary keys.

**Thanks To**

- [How to get item from list?](https://serverfault.com/a/1111552/448950)
- [How can I select 1 item by index the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544271/6771046)

**Further Reading**

regarding the order of dictionary keys

- [Order of elements of dict objects of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72498717/6771046)
- [Ansible Issue #17763 - Add support for `OrderedDict`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/17763)

Comment: needed to use msg: "{{ (cluster_info.clusters | list)[cluster_input.user_input|int -1] }}" to get the right selection

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the dict instead and produce output only if the loop index matches the user input:

```
- set_fact:
    {% for name in cluster_info.clusters -%}
        {% if loop.index == cluster_input.user_input -%}
    vcenter_cluster: "{{ name }}"
        {%- endif %}
    {%- endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell:

```yaml
- hosts: your_group

  vars:
    vcenter_cluster: "{{ cluster_info.clusters.keys()[cluster_input.user_input] }}"

  tasks:
    - ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: vcenter_cluster
```